# Something wrong with the loop in the Console

Tags: javascript, html, loops, onclick, console

I created a simple code where the parent element, which is the `<ul>`, removes a single child, which is `<li>`, every time it is clicked. The execution was successful, but every time I click the parent element, there is a message in the console that says there is something wrong with my code. You will see it when you copy and paste this code:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
query('ul').onclick = function() {
    var childItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.children);
    for(var c=0; c<childItems.length; ++c) {
        while(childItems.length != 0) {
            this.removeChild(childItems[c]);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

when you use slice method, it returns a new array. Then when you use removeChild you are using this new array and not the node list.The error that you are getting is related with the array is not belong to the ul node.

you can fix,

```
query('ul').onclick = function(e) {
    this.removeChild(this.children[0]);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5g6767h1/

Comment: I don't think that is correct, the reference to the node is preserved, Array.prototype.slice.call changes a nodelist to an array structure

Comment: I didn't think it could be that simple. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't nest a `while` loop inside of an unnecessary `for` loop, and I also wouldn't use `Array.prototype.slice.call()`. Regardless of either of that, the code that you implemented with the `for` and `while` loop will remove *all* of the elements on the first click, instead of removing them one by one. The suggested way to do this (example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp)) is to use the childNodes member of your `ul`. For example:

```
yourUL.onclick = function() {
    this.removeChild(this.childNodes[0]);
};
```

Let me throw this in a fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o2om4v2n/)

Comment: Why not use array.protype.slice.call?  Also why are you removing elements one by one.  You are right about the redundant while loop though.

Comment: @nick The OP requested "removes a single child, which is <li>, every time it is clicked". That is why I am removing them one by one.

Comment: I wouldn't use `Array.prototype.slice.call()` mostly just because of redundancy. If there is already a member `childNodes` of the object, why use something else?

Comment: type conversion isn't redundant, you can call array methods like forEach on an array of nodes after you convert from a nodeList.  But anyway that's irrelevant if he is just trying to remove a single element.

Comment: Thanks for all of your tips. I didn't think it could be as simple as that. I'm not good yet at making complicated codes.

Comment: @MichaelFourre I tested your code. What happened was I have to double click the `<ul>` to remove one child

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="TestUL">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
var ul = document.getElementById('test');
ul.onclick = function() {
    var childItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.children);
    for(var c=0; c<childItems.length; ++c) {
        while(childItems.length != 0) {
            this.removeChild(childItems[c]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain *why* and *how* this is better than the original code.